# Prove that $\sum=CC^T\Rightarrow \sum^{-1}=C^TC$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

For $\sum$ covariance matrix ($n\times n$, symmetric and positive definite) and $C$ lower triangular matrix with real and positive entries, how can I prove the equivalence as from title?

I know that the inverse of a lower triangular matrix is again lower triangular. I also know that $(C^T)^{-1}=(C^{-1})^T$. Thus:

$\sum=CC^T \Rightarrow \sum^{-1}=(CC^T)^{-1}=(C^{-1})(C^T)^{-1}=(C^{-1})(C^{-1})^T=CC^T$ with abuse of notation.

But I have to obtain that $\sum^{-1}=C^TC$. Where I wrong?

Comment: $(CC^T)^{-1} = (C^T)^{-1} C^{-1}$ :)

Comment: @cvanaret Why this equivalence?

Comment: If square matrices $M,N$ are invertible, then $(MN)^{-1}=N^{-1}M^{-1}$, i.e., there's a change in the order.

Comment: Is $C^{-1}=C$ an additional assumption of yours?

Comment: @Hanno Inverse of a lower triangular matrix is lower triangular, so for $C$ lower triangular I write $C^{-1}=C$ with misuse of notation.

Comment: This is more than a misuse: it is misleading. You should really avoid it.